# Angularjs : enabled ng-click on disabled input

Tags: angularjs

How can I enabled ng-click on a text input even if the input is disabled?

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myModel" ng-click="vm.handleClick()" ng-disabled="true" />
```

Comment: if you really want it. Try trick by class `disable`, and regex prevent any action input in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a wrapper  and bind ng-click on it. i.e.

```
<div ng-click='ur_Function()'>
<input type="text" ng-model="myModel"  ng-disabled="true" />
</div>
```

U can check in your function whether input enabled  is true or false and perform accordingly

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible in fact. Each AngularJS directive has its own priority. You may notice that [ngDisabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) has priority 100, while [ngClick](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) set at 0. Moreover, `ngDisabled` required to set native input `disabled` attribute, because it does not support interpolation.

Speaking about native input [disabled state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/disabled):

> If the element is disabled, it does not respond to user actions, it
>   cannot be focused, and the command event will not fire.

Other words - if it is disabled then it is disabled and no events are possible. Otherwise `disabled` directive would be meaningless.